# Web Scraping: XPath for Pagination

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, pagination

I am trying to scrape a few company websites with Octoparse. I can't seem to get my XPath right for pagination. The website pages do not have a 'Next' button. I am trying to scrape data from each page.
Any suggestions?

I have tried the following XPath (along with a few other failures):

```
//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/section/div[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/a/following-sibling::li[1]/a
```

Here is an example of a company [website](https://jobs.mayoclinic.org/job-search/?br_location=Florida&pager=1) I am testing it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I modified Redyukov Pavel's solution which worked:

```
//a[@class='current']/../following-sibling::li[1]/a[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need page next from the current page. This is quite qasy with `following-sibling`

```
//li[./a[@class="current"]]/following-sibling::li[1]
```

You can read about this  [here](http://w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Comment: The scraper would just stop after the first page when I used the XPath you gave. However, I was able to modify your solution which worked (I posted as an answer). Thanks for the help!